# How to programmatically check if Kafka Broker is up and running in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I'm trying to consume messages from a Kafka topic. I'm using a wrapper around `confluent_kafka` consumer. I need to check if connection is established before I start consuming messages.

I read that the consumer is lazy, so I need to perform some action for the connection to get established. But I want to check the connection establishment without doing a `consume` or `poll` operation.

Also, I tried giving some bad configurations to see what the response on a poll would be. The response I got was:

```
b'Broker: No more messages'
```

So, how do I decide if the connection parameters are faulty, the connection is broken, or there actually are no messages in the topic?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am afraid there is no direct approach for testing whether Kafka Brokers are up and running. Also note that if your consumer has already consumed the messages it doesn't mean that this is a bad behaviour and obviously it does not indicate that the Kafka broker is down.

---

A possible workaround would be to perform some sort of quick operation and see if the broker responds. An example would be listing the topics:

**Using [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) and [`AdminClient`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/#pythonclient-adminclient)**

```
# Example using confuent_kafka
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient

kafka_broker = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'}
admin_client = AdminClient(kafka_broker)
topics = admin_client.list_topics().topics

if not topics: 
    raise RuntimeError()
```

**Using [`kafka-python`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) and [`KafkaConsumer`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/#kafkaconsumer)**

```
# example using kafka-python
import kafka


consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(group_id='test', bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
topics = consumer.topics()

if not topics: 
    raise RuntimeError()
```

Use kafka-python at your own risk, library has not been updated in years, might not be compatible with amazon msk or confluent containers

Comment: when a producer writes to a topic, how can I get it's status to check whether it's free or busy in writing?

Comment: or in another case if the producer itself is down?